# Dynamic UserControl Not Showing - flowlayoutpanel

Tags: vb.net

I've array of items and for each item, creating a new instance of custom user control. The problem is that when the control is created and added to Flowlayoutpanel, it's not showing up.

**Code**

```
Sub createList()
    Dim len_ids As Integer = account_ids.Length - 1
    Dim x As Integer = 1

    While x <= len_ids
        Dim listItem As New wrapperItems()

        listItem.txtName.Text = account_names(x)
        listItem.picIcon.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(account_icons(x))
        listItem.lblPath.Text = account_paths(x)
        listItem.Tag = "listItem" & x
        listItem.Top = 10 * x
        listItem.Left = 10
        Me.flowWrapper1.Controls.Add(listItem)
        listItem.Show() ' tried this
        listItem.Visible = True 'tried this
        listItem.BringToFront() ' tried this
        x += 1
    End While
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Anyone has idea of why it's not working?

Comment: I would suggest first try adding your  control through the designer and then try programatically

Comment: Did you check it width and height in debugger after `Me.flowWrapper1.Controls.Add(listItem)`?

Comment: Usually it is due to control being behind another control or the position is not correct.  Looking at you code a top offset of 10 is too small.  I think it is better to to get height of previous control and add height to get next control top.

Comment: @jdweng I tried that using .location property. It doesnt show..

Comment: @ChiragMM Did that already. It shows up when dragged and droped in flowpanel

Comment: @StanisalvDontsov No. I've specifid the usercontrol width and height while designing it. Will check again

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the background worker is started on Form.Show instead of Form.Load, the code doesn't work. 
For the fix, I added background worker to Form.Load().

The better way was finally to add a refresh list button and then load the background worker.